# spline fit using python code version 2.7 (reading from excel file the values of x and y)

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to simply read in two columns of data (values) as an X and Y from my Excel file (sheet1) and do a spline curve fit to the data. so I would be able to pick any desired value of x (lets say 2.6) and calculate y.

Can you please guide me on this?

I have tried two methods below, none of them works!

## two ways I tried to do this:

## first method:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook


#read  from excel file

wb = load_workbook('python_excel_read.xlsx')

sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


x = np.zeros(sheet1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(sheet1.max_row)

for i in range(0,sheet1.max_row):
    x[i]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value
    y[i]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value



def f(x):
    x_current = [x]
    y_voltage = [y]


    tck = interpolate.splrep(x_current, y_voltage)
    return interpolate.splev(x, tck)

print f(2.6)
```

## my second method:

```
from scipy import interpolate

import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('python_excel_read.xlsx')
sht = xw.Book('Sheet1')

x_current = sht.range1('A2:A40').value
y_voltage = sht.range2('B2:B40').value


def f(x):
    x_current = [sht.range1]
    y_voltage = [sht.range2]


    tck = interpolate.splrep(x_current, y_voltage)
    return interpolate.splev(x, tck)

print f(2.6)
```

Comment: Please provide some data and explain in detail what does not work. Right now it is hard to help as it is unclear what your actual problem is.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment the actual problem is with neither of above method this would run. basically something must be wrong with the code or how it is written. I am wondering someone could add their own way of doing this. I simply want to read two column of data let's say X and Y and do a spline fit to help me extrapolate to any value within that range. In my example that value was 2